# ASP.Net File upload to FTP server

Tags: asp.net, file, uploader

I want to create a file uploader. User chooses file using website, and the main problem is I have to save that file to ftp server which is another computer... Any suggestions? 
Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [faq] to see which questions you may ask here. Currently this question is far too broad.

Comment: Handle the file as a standard HTML form file post and then upload to FTP on the server side.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this yet?  There's an `FtpWebRequest` class that may be a good place to start.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: you should reconsider why you want to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly write dynamic files to an FTP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146901/how-to-correctly-write-dynamic-files-to-an-ftp-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can save it by passing IP address of that pc, if another pc is connected with LAN then you can do this by passing IP address with folder details where you want to save that file.

But that folder must be shared to network using that only you can save file to another pc.

Thank you.