# How to enable RetainSameConnection on FTP connection within SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have inherited some SSIS Packages written against SQL Server 2008.  Among these is one offending package that is fetching files from a small device via FTP.  It is creating a new connection for each file.  Which overwhelms the device quickly.

In efforts to fix this I found multiple references on using the **`RetainSameConnection`** property.  However I have gone through the properties and it is not available to set.  I have not been able to find how to via searching either.  Or if it is available in SQLServer 2008

So my question is simply, How can I get at that property?  Or what version does it become available if not in SQL Server 2008?

[image: FTP Connection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer the central question here: the *RetainSameConnection* property isn't available for the FTP Connection Manager.

Without diving into why the device is being overwhelmed by FTP requests (requests are pretty cheap in both I/O and CPU, after all), one suggestion would be to use an Execute Process task that calls a command-line FTP client (such as Window's native *ftp*) and uses a batch file to pass in the arguments to send across to the FTP server to (for example) copy an entire remote directory down to a local directory.

Comment: As I suspected..  Thanks for the alternative path, I'll try that to pull the files.  As for the why the device is overwhelemed it is a small ARM based data acquisition device (AcquiSuite A8812) and the current process is making 3-6 connections /sec.  when it fires

Answer (score 0):

#### Standard:

Standard *FTP Connection* does not have **`RetainSameConnection`** option.

#### Alternative option 1:

You could use *`Script Task`* to transfer files your local folder and FTP website. Here are couple of SO question that relate to FTP transfer through *Script Task*.

[How to avoid SSIS FTP task from failing when there are no files to download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140850/how-to-avoid-ssis-ftp-task-from-failing-when-there-are-no-files-to-download)

[How to write stored procedure output directly to a file on an FTP without using local or temp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587/how-to-write-stored-procedure-output-directly-to-a-file-on-an-ftp-without-using)

#### Alternative option 2:

You could make use of the [SFTP Task](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/sftp-task) sold by third party vendor *CozyRoc*. Personally, I have not used the component but it does come with the *`RetainSameConnection`* property. Read the section *`Data streaming`* at the end of the page where they state this option.

Comment: I just read about that CozyRoc solution.  Interesting, but the cost..
As Kyle pointed out I'm going to try the script path solution.